# Why does the `move` cursor have no shadow? (OSX Lion)

Tags: css, cursor

In Chrome on OSX, the `move` cursor [has no shadow](https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/10819/42395/muhf06n1nx7iqgs/Cursor%20move%20-%20no%20shadow.m4v), while `default`, `pointer`, and many others do.

Is this happening at the OS level? Is Chrome using some sort of custom cursor, triggering OSX to render it differently than "built in" cursors?

Are there any ways (besides specifying a custom cursor image) to add the shadow back?

[Cursor reference](http://www.worldtimzone.com/mozilla/testcase/css3cursors.html)

Comment: It's the same in Safari but not Firefox, which hints pretty strongly that it's a WebKit cursor (the FF `move` cursor is a hand). Do you see the same in Chrome/Safari/Firefox on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

The cursors in Chrome seem to be the Mac OS X system cursors and the `move` cursor doesn't have a shadow. For what it's worth, the crosshair and the text selection (I-beam) cursors are also missing the drop shadow. You could either supply your own cursor image using url() or just accept that there will be some platform differences and when Apple updates their cursor assets (like they did when they updated the hand/pointer cursor recently, and added High-res Retina versions of their cursors) your web site/app will automatically use them.